# Does Bitcoin Core support BIP157? (some call it neutrino)

Tags: lightning-network, compact-client-side-block-filters

I want to allow my bitcoind node to support BIP157 so that i can allow some friends to connect their LND nodes to it.
Does it support it by default?
Or do i need to explicitly enable it?

Answer (score 7):

Bitcoin Core 0.21+ support BIP 157, but not necessarily by default. In 0.21, it is default to off. You can enable it by adding `peerblockfilters=1` to your bitcoin.conf file.